# How to use SubjectPublicKeyInfo encrypt data?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm newer to RSA and used BC get SubjectPublicKeyInfo from a public key.

```
String key = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
             "........\n" +// Multiple lines here
             "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
PEMParser reader = new PEMParser(new StringReader(key));
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) reader.readObject();
```

And then I want encrypt datas. I found some one use RSAEngine to do it:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter aKey = (RSAKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo);
AsymmetricBlockCipher engine = new RSAEngine();
engine.init(false, aKey);
byte[] dataEncrypted = engine.processBlock(data, 0, data.length);
```

**After I run those code**, I found the result isn't equal to the expection. **So I want to know is there any mistake in my code?**

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: @AlexK Updated my question. I had run my code ,but the result isn't to be the expection. So I don't know whether my code is correct way to do the RSA encryption or not.

Comment: the question you need to answer is WHAT IS THE RESULT, and WHAT DID YOU EXPECT THE RESULT TO BE

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my way out.

If anyone is familiar with `BouncyCastle`, he can point me the low-level mistakes.

Firstly, to encrypt data should init `Engine` with true at first arg in `init` function.

Secondly, my public key is start with '**-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----**'. It's **PKCS#1** format RSA public key and should use `BouncyCastle` to read in, but encrypt data should have `padding`. So, I shouldn't use `RSAEngine` directly, use `PKCS1Encoding` instead.

At last , post my encrypt code and decrypt code:

Encryption:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
PEMParser reader = new PEMParser(new StringReader(key));
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) reader.readObject();
RSAKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RSAKeyParameters)          
PublicKeyFactory.createKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo);
PKCS1Encoding engine = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
engine.init(true, rsaKeyParameters);
return engine.processBlock(data, 0, data.length);
```

Decryption:

```
public static byte[] decryptByPublicKey(String data, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawData = Base64.decode(data);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PEMParser reader = new PEMParser(new StringReader(key));
    PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair) reader.readObject();
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = pemKeyPair.getPublicKeyInfo();
    PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = pemKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo();
    RSAKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RSAKeyParameters)     
    PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(privateKeyInfo);
    PKCS1Encoding engine = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
    engine.init(false, rsaKeyParameters);
    return engine.processBlock(rawData, 0, rawData.length);
}
```

For encryption , you can use modulus and public exponent to create a key that support by JDK:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PEMParser reader = new PEMParser(new StringReader(key));
    PemObject obj = reader.readPemObject();
    org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey.getInstance(obj.getContent());
    BigInteger modulus = rsaPublicKey.getModulus();
    BigInteger publicExponent = rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent();

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
    PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");//This line should use right padding.For PKCS#1 format RSA key , it should be this.
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
```

See Also:[Basic RSA example.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm)